# Installing GraphQL iOS Framework

Tags: ios, graphql, apollo

I want to add the apollo framework to my iOS project. I'm following the [documentation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/ios/installation.html#installing-framework) but can't build it.

1. I install apollo via cocoapods
2. I add a code generation build step to my target (put it above compile sources...)
3. I download the schema via apollo schema:download --endpoint=http://localhost:4000/graphql schema.json. I add schema.json file to the root directory in my project.
4. I build it and get the following error:

   - apollo@1.2.0
     added 416 packages in 20.385s
     ++ exec /Users/PATH/node_modules/.bin/apollo codegen:generate --queries= --schema=schema.json API.swift
     ›   Warning: apollo update available from 1.2.0 to 1.7.0
     ›   **Error: Flag --queries expects a value**
     Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 2

My **schema.grapqhl** file looks something like:

```
type Query {
  """ User """
  users: [User!]!
  user(username: String!): User

  """ Question """
  questions: [Question!]!
  question(id: Int!): Question

  }

  type Mutation {
  """ User """
    createUser(username: String!): User
    updateUser(username: String!, newUsername: String!): [Int!]!
    deleteUser(username: String!): Int!

  """ Question """
    createQuestion(text: String!, category: Int!, active: Boolean!): 
    Question
    updateQuestion(id: Int!, text: String!, category: Int!, active: Boolean!): [Int!]!
    deleteQuestion(id: Int!): Int!
 }

 type Subscription {
   answerAdded: Answer
 }

 type Question {
  id: Int!
  text: String!
  categoryId: QuestionCategory!
  active: Boolean!
  createdAt: String!
  updatedAt: String!
  }
  ......
```

It seems that the query param doesnt have an input:
apollo codegen:generate --queries= --schema=schema.json API.swift

If i try it myself via terminal

```
apollo codegen:generate --queries=schema.graphql --schema=schema.json API.swift
```

I get the following error:

```
Warning: apollo update available from 1.2.0 to 1.7.0
.../schema.graphql: The Query definition is not executable.
.../schema.graphql: The Mutation definition is not executable.
.../schema.graphql: The Subscription definition is not executable.
.../schema.graphql: The Question definition is not executable.
... some more ...
:heavy_check_mark: Scanning for GraphQL queries (1 found)
:heavy_check_mark: Loading GraphQL schema
:heavy_check_mark: Parsing GraphQL schema
:heavy_multiplication_x: Generating query files with 'swift' target
 → Validation of GraphQL query document failed
ToolError: Validation of GraphQL query document failed
at Object.validateQueryDocument 
....
```

Can you please help to find out why I can't build the project? Is it because my schema.graphl file is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

as answered by @Sergej Birklin I would like to share another query with you-

**Profile.graphql**

```
query MyProfile{
    player {
        me {
            id
            secret
            name
            email
            state
            country
            timezone
            picture
            pictureType
            audio
            rank
        }
    }
}
```

As simply we're queering the my profile info (where the me is as a **player** type), the query will return with the information I required like my ID, name, email, state etc.

> as you state that it will create MyProfileQuery

Hope this will help you out

#swith #GraphQL #iOS

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [Martijn Walraven](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4494248/martijn-walraven) on the open Apollo Slack iOS Channel I solved it.

The problem is that my schema.graphql file is wrong.

> your `schema.graphql` file is a representation of your schema in the schema definition language, not a query document. apollo ios expects you to define the queries your app uses in `.graphql` files, so it can generate code from them.
>   these are the queries the client sends to the server, similar to what you would put in graphiql for example
>
> ... queries need to be named. so if you put this in a `.graphql` file:

```
query AllQuestions {
  queries {
    text
  }
}
```

> that will generate a `AllQuestionsQuery` swift class that you can pass to `client.fetch(query:)`
>   and it will also generate result types with the exact fields you requested (edited)
>   so you can access `text`, but not `active` for example
>   so in contrast to global model types, query-specific types give you complete type safety for your data fetching

Comment: This article will help you too [Mapping GraphQL types to Swift](https://blog.apollographql.com/mapping-graphql-types-to-swift-aa85e5693db4)